# HTML 5 Video keep looping even I set it not to loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, attributes, html5-video

I have this example here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IqbCB

Would like to ask I removed from the JS 'loop="loop"' but its still looping. I would like the background video to play only once. I am tearing my hair off what is wrong :)

I changed this:

```
html += '<video class="hidden-xs hidden-sm" id="'+plugin.settings.videoid+'" preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"';
```

to this:

```
html += '<video class="hidden-xs hidden-sm" id="'+plugin.settings.videoid+'" preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay"';
```

and still nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be caused by this line:

```
plugin.$videoEl.bind('ended', function(){ this.play(); });
```

Which is pretty self-explanatory (upon [ended](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974154%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event, the video is played again using `.play()`)

Removing this line (and removing the `loop` attribute entirely) allows it to be [played only once](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGxhA).

Comment: omg, I am honestly embarrassed right now, I oversaw that, thank you :)